OData Connected Services DataServiceVersion 2.0
Tried to create context from edmx and use it. I was expecting context to be create to OData protocol version 2.0, but it creates it to Version 3.0.
Im also wondering is OData Protocol 2.0 version also kind a old. And if service owner isn't updating version, is only option to write requests from the long stuff. It is doable, but HTTP PATCH with C# object tracking with only modified properties on big context is kind time taking.
I started to wonder this, because
OData Connected Service cannot create fully working context and tries to create the context to version 3.0, while DataServiceVersion-attribute is set to 2.0.
There is also an issue with edmx-file and i am not sure which is the issue:

namespace cannot recognize the version attribute and not even Schema-element
Namespace should be "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
also tried "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" link with no luck

Connected Service creates context for wrong version and wanted schemas isnt selectable in Connected Service wizard
Context is created but CRUD-functions are not working right and DataServiceProtocolVersion cannot be changed afterwards or using service on the go.
Ok, i know that CRUD could be write from start with long stuff, but working Connected Service could really be a great help. This decision would be long lasting.
Any experts on this?
